# Not Operator in Javascript gives Unexpected Token Error

Tags: javascript, if-statement, logical-operators, not-operator

Using a not operator (`!`) in this conditional gives me:

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token !"

```js
if (text.includes(input[j])) {
   $(Messages[i]).hide();
}
else if !(text.includes(input[j])) {
   $(Messages[i]).show();
}
```

Why isn't `!` working here?

Answer (score 7):

`!` should be within `()`:

```
else if (!text.includes(input[j]))
```